# Node.js and express ReferenceError: response is not defined

Tags: node.js, express

Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config.json"));
console.log(config);
var host = config.host;
var port = config.port;

var app = express.createServer();

// use route
app.use(app.router);

// for static files this location
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// root path
app.get('/', function (request, response) {

    response.send("hello");
});


app.get("/id/:id", function (request, reponse) {


    var value = request.params.id;
    console.log(value);
    response.send(value.toString());

});

app.listen(port, host);
```

I can log whatever is the value after id in the url   127.0.0.1:3317/id/**hello**

Hello is printed in the console but there is a **ReferenceError: response is not defined**  error.

Please Help me out

Comment: You have a typo `reponse`. You should probably do some more debugging before coming here.

Answer (score 22):

**response** is misspelled *reponse*.

Comment: The same here :D Same typo wth.

Comment: I spelled everything correctly. Well, crud... edit: response was used outside of its function, derp. More coffee...

Comment: I had this same typo and it took me like 10 minutes to find this answer incredibly helpful. Thanks for inspiring me to re-read my code.

Comment: "repsonse" wasted me 10 minutes. Ugh. This helped. Thanks.